# Linux System Desktop Completely Frozen

Tags: linux, parrotsec

Running an up to date version of ParrotSec OS under VirtualBox.

System has been running fine for weeks.

My desktop is now completely frozen, no mouse or keyboard input, no special commands can be forced - nothing.

I've reset the system a few times, nada.

The last commands given to the system were:

```
apt-get install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms
```

Install was successful and now frozen.

The only thing I can do is enter the system via a recovery prompt.

`Alt+SysRq + REISUB` does nothing either.

Help on how to resolve please :)